# Duplicate iTunes podcast folder – which one is correct?

Tags: macos, mac, itunes, ipod, podcasts

Recently a extra podcast "tab" (for lack of a better word) appeared in iTunes after I subscribed to a couple of podcasts via RSS. Only the new podcasts show in that new tab (I'll call it Tab 2). All the podcasts I had before appear to be in the original one (Tab 1).

However, when I try to sync my iPod now, I get the message that ‘Podcasts on the iPod “[iPod name]” cannot be synced because all of the podcasts selected for syncing no longer exist.’

I'm guessing that the podcasts in Tab 1 are in this folder: Music > iTunes > iTunes Music > Podcasts.
The new podcasts in Tab 2 appear to be in Music > iTunes > iTunes Media > Podcasts.

The weird thing (or one weird thing) is that there are a number of other podcast folders and files in that Tab 2 / iTunes Media > Podcasts folder, even though the two new podcasts are the only ones visible in iTunes. They are all podcasts that I've subscribed to – and ones that are in the other folder (Tab 1 / iTunes Music > Podcasts) too – but the individual podcast episodes appear to be different.

Have I thoroughly confused everyone now? Any suggestions on how to fix this without losing anything?

Comment: Unsubscribe from all podcasts. Delete the tabs if you can. Close iTunes. Delete the two folders. Open iTunes. Subscribe again. I think it was version 8 or 9 where the folder was renamed to iTunes Media, so that's where it'll recreate the folders when you resubscribe.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Randolph. Is there any way to go about it without losing all my old stuff? There are podcasts I subscribed to years ago that aren't available any longer.

If I simply move the files from the old folder to whatever new iTunes Media podcast folder is created, would that at least get them to show up in iTunes? 

I'm guessing I'll lose the info on what I listened to and when, ratings, etc. though. Is there any way to keep that from happening?

Comment: Everything will go if you unsubscribe. As they're all MP3s, you could move them to another location and reimport them, but they'll show up as audio files in the main iTunes collective.